# how to get values from edit text in fragments of a tabbed activity in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

**Code :**

```
 public class CustomerDetails extends Fragment {
    EditText CustomerCode,FullName,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,MobileNo,EmailId,CustomerType;
    Button Submit;
    IonExchangeDataBasehelper  ionexchangedatabase;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           // View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customer_details,container,false);
            View v =getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_customer_details,null);
            CustomerCode=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.CustomerCode);
            FullName=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.FullName);
            AddressLine1=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.AddressLine1);
            AddressLine2=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.AddressLine2);
            MobileNo=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.MobileNo);
            EmailId=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.EmailId);
            CustomerType=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.CustomerType);
            Submit=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Submit);

            Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String abc = CustomerCode.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"hhh :" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  //  database();
                }
            });

            return v;

        }
```

Comment: What is an error? Is edittext in activity?

Comment: You mean to say, how to retrieve value from EditText?

Comment: no its in fragment , but i m not able to get the values from edittext

Comment: yes i want to retrieve value

Comment: @RAJSHINDE you are not printing values in toast

Comment: but it should display toast ,but it is also not able to display simple toast

Comment: @RAJSHINDE use this **`View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customer_details, container, false);`**

Comment: i have used that before but then to its not coming toast is not working in fragments  of tabbed activity

Comment: Your code seems ok. Make sure each id is correct

Comment: yes each id is perfect i have checked in  20 times

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned your code; try it and say if you still get errors

```
  public class CustomerDetails extends Fragment {
                EditText customerCode,fullName,addressLine1,addressLine2,mobileNo,emailId,customerType;
                Button submit;
                IonExchangeDataBasehelper  ionexchangedatabase;

                   @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customer_details, container, 
        false);
        // get the reference of views
                        customerCode=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.CustomerCode);
                        fullName=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.FullName);
                        addressLine1=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.AddressLine1);
                        addressLine2=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.AddressLine2);
                        mobileNo=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.MobileNo);
                        emailId=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.EmailId);
                        customerType=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.CustomerType);
                        submit=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Submit);

                        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                String abc = customerCode.getText().toString();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), abc ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              //  database();
                            }
                        });

                        return v;

                    }
```